# Listing folders in CMD which does NOT have a specific subfolder

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, dir

I've an issue where i need to locate all folders on a drive which does NOT have a folder in them called "Arg".. I know how to do it in reverse using DIR, i.e to find all subfolder with a specific name, but as I need the opposite of that.. I rely on superuser wisdom to help Me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `FOR`/`IF NOT EXIST` are your friends, in this case...

For immediate subfolders of the current folder...

```
for /d %A in (*) do @if not exist "%~fA\Arg\*" echo %~fA
```

Or recursively, from current folder down...

```
for /d /r %A in (*) do @if not exist "%~fA\Arg\*" echo %~fA
```

Or recursively, from a given path...

```
for /d /r X:\pathto %A in (*) do @if not exist "%~fA\Arg\*" echo %~fA
```

Conversely...

```
for /d %A in (*) do @if exist "%~fA\Arg\*" echo %~fA
for /d /r %A in (*) do @if exist "%~fA\Arg\*" echo %~fA
for /d /r X:\pathto %A in (*) do @if exist "%~fA\Arg\*" echo %~fA
```

In a batch file, you would need to escape the `%` symbol...

```
for /d %%A in (*) do @if exist "%%~fA\Arg\*" echo %%~fA
for /d /r %%A in (*) do @if exist "%%~fA\Arg\*" echo %%~fA
for /d /r X:\pathto %%A in (*) do @if exist "%%~fA\Arg\*" echo %~fA

for /d %%A in (*) do @if not exist "%%~fA\Arg\*" echo %%~fA
for /d /r %%A in (*) do @if not exist "%%~fA\Arg\*" echo %%~fA
for /d /r X:\pathto %%A in (*) do @if not exist "%%~fA\Arg\*" echo %~fA
```

If you're doing it regularly, perhaps a macro...

```
doskey nosubdir=for /d %A in (*) do @if not exist "%~fA\$*\*" echo %~fA
doskey nosubdirrec=for /d /r %A in (*) do @if not exist "%~fA\$*\*" echo %~fA
...
cd /d x:\pathto
nosubdir Arg
nosubdirrec Arg
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you can run recursive dir and redirect its output to a file, then you are halfway through. The rest can be done with the find command that looks for lines that contain or do not contain the given string.

Here I listed my directories into mydirs.lst.
First, I looked for directories containing the string "Links", then I did the opposite by using the /v switch.

Comment: Can you do some sort of diff on the list then to find out the folders which has it and don't?